# cant locate vim in usr/share or /bin

Tags: command-line, vim

Wanted to do a clean install of vim as I had messed up the `usr/share/vim` files quite a bit installing plugins and messing with things there, instead of creating a `.vim` in my home directory like I should have. I have a text file of my `vimrc` so reverting to default was fine. However, purging and reinstalling Vim did not change any of the altered vimfiles in bin.

Messing around and I must've deleted the `usr/bin/vim` by mistake because I can't find it. Now removing and reinstalling vim does not replace it. Vim will still open, but behaves kinda funny. I still can't locate the vim files, although `whereis` and `echo $PATH` all state it is there. Any ideas? this is driving me nuts.

```
$ whereis vim    
vim: /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim.basic /usr/bin/vim.tiny /etc/vim /usr/bin/X11/vim /usr/bin/X11/vim.basic /usr/bin/X11/vim.tiny /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz


$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/loc
al/games


$ update-alternatives --display vim    
vim - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/vim.basic
/usr/bin/vim.basic - priority 30
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/vim.basic'.

$ type -a vim
   /usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the output of `whereis vim`, `echo $PATH` - without giving us the output, saying that they state it is "there" is meaningless. Also add the output of `update-alternatives --display vim`, and `type -a vim`.

Comment: Ouch. I stated it should be in 'usr/bin/' and that its now not showing there. as well as being the path of the echo. anyway, i provided the output you asked for. i apologize for my ambiguity, but 'meaningless' is a little extreme. do i have to state that i'm brand new to this site and linux in every post to not get crapped on for asking for help?

Comment: No, but you should give us the data, and let us interpret it ourselves. If you're brand new to something, why would you give your interpretation and not the actual data?

Comment: Try `apt-get install --reinstall vim vim-common vim-runtime`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete fresh install of vim, try this:

```
apt purge vim
```

And watch the output of that command for warnings like: could not delete so-and-so directory because it was not empty. Then delete those yourself. Then reinstall vim and it will be a fresh install.